# Getting “Command Not Found” when attempting to use R on macOS El Capitan (10.11.3)

Tags: macos, bash, links, r

I am working on a new machine running on macOS El Capitan (10.11.3). On the terminal, `R` returns `-bash: R: command not found` (and similar for `r`). In the meantime `open -a R` works fine and opens the console.

What can I do to be able to run scripts with `R --vanilla` from the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me

1. Disable `rootless` feature. [Here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-os-x-10-11) is an easy recipe on how to proceed.
2. Uninstall and reinstall `R` (to obtain the links in `/usr/bin`)
3. Quit and reopen the terminal (not sure if necessary)

[Here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mac/2015-October/011632.html) is the post who inspired this solution